# how to convert string into object using json.parse?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a problem with converting string into object in nodejs. `JSON.parse` is not working. whenever I'm trying to use that it gives me a syntax error like this:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

how do I convert string into object???

```
socket.on('user details', function(data, socketId){
   console.log('message', data );


var socketID = JSON.parse(socketId);

Socketdb.findOne({'socketId': socketID})
 .exec(function(err, userData){
   console.log('registering the socket');
   if(err){
    console.log('error occured');
    console.log(err);

   }else{
    if(userData !== null){
     console.log('.........................failed.............................');

   }else{

    var socketdb = new Socketdb();
    socketdb.socketId = socketID;

    socketdb.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log('something is wrong');
        console.log(err);
        //res.json({message: 'register failed', details: 'user adding unsuccessful', content: userData});
      }else{
       // res.json({message: 'success', details: 'userData added successful', content: userData})
        console.log('user success');
        io.emit('user details', data);

      }
    });

   }
   }

 });
```

Comment: What is `socketId` ? To use `JSON.parse`, you need to have a valid JSON string, that starts with `{`

Comment: By the way, don't try to parse a full socket object. There is a high chance of it having a circular reference, which will output an error along the lines of "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: if not parse the full socket object then what should I parse? i've been struggling here for days i really need some help....

Comment: socketId = socket.id

Comment: You don't need to parse. What you call `socketId` is already an object. This explains your error, since JSON.parse tries to parse a string. However, `socketId` being an object, it's like doing `JSON.parse({})` which will throw the exact same error you are having, because it boils down to `JSON.parse("object")`

Comment: yeah I got it now.. thanks for the help.